# Reducing 16.5VDC battery output to the range of 13.8VDC +- 15% without introducing noise for 15 Amp load

Tags: voltage-regulator, dc, dc-dc-converter, conversion

The title pretty much says it all. The (up to) 15A load is a ham radio, which is the reason for the 'no noise' constraint. Maybe a tiny bit of noise is OK? I don't know how I could tell.

To save you the calculation, 13.8VDC +- 15% = 11.73VDC to 15.87VDC

Of course I've thought about a buck/boost DC to DC converter, but I hear those are too noisy. Is there some kind of signal cleaner I could drop in after the converter?

What about a voltage divider? Could that work?

LM7812 seems like a possibility, but won't I be seeing huge losses? Not to mention I'd probably need 10 of them in parallel.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to the site. There are more linear regulators in the world than the 1 A 78xx series :-) But whatever linear reg', it was, it'd drop 2.7 V x 15 A = 40.5 W worst case. So unless you can stand the heat drop and and battery wastage, forget linears, which leaves you with a switching regulator. So you need to quantify what low noise is before you can proceed. Edit your question (not add comments) and improve it, adding much technical detail (nothing we must look up, like model numbers or links). The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract.

Comment: Would you consider a big honkin' silicon diode dropper? Crude, but just might fit your spec.

Comment: It is possible to build switching regulators for radios (it's how vibrator supplies for tube radios worked, in a primitive way).  You just have to work extra-hard to keep the noise down.  You should ask this question on a ham radio forum -- someone has already done it, for sure.

Comment: So you're only concerned about audiable noise. any modern switching supply in the hundreds of kilohertz would do this.

Comment: A have radio design to run off vehicle voltage is not noise-immune, how did that happen?

Comment: there's a circuit in the LM7812 datasheet that shows how to boost the current capability of a 7812 by adding a large PNP transistor,  you'll be needing a 60W heat-sink

Answer (score 3):

Two silicon diodes in series will knock 1.2V off the supply, getting you 15.3V

perhaps use a 15A rectifier bridge connected in reverse, add a heat-sink.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCpmec.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

> What about a voltage divider? Could that work?

It would waste a lot of power, and would not regulate the voltage

For noise? use an adjustable linear regulator, which you'll need to parallel a few of them for the current output. This will also waste power, which probably isn't the best thing for a battery powered application.

A DC to DC in combination with paralleled linear regulators would be the best of the low noise and power worlds.

Find a DC to DC module and make sure you shield it, it also helps if the switching frequency is not near your frequencies of interest. If you could get the DC to DC to drop to 14.25V then use a few LDO's to regulate the voltage to 13.8V. The [LT1764](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1764fb.pdf) might be a good choice with a .45V dropout at 3A. You would need to have 4 or 5 in parallel as they can only support 3A (4A max). 0.45V*15A is rougly 7W which would be a little over a watt per a device. (if you wanted to only parallel LDO's you would want to run more than 5 because the power dissipation would be around 40W.)

[image]

Here are some options on paralleling:

[image]
http://rohmfs.rohm.com/en/products/databook/applinote/ic/power/linear_regulator/parallel_ldo_an-e.pdf